# Will the upcoming Seraphis upgrade change anything with regard to the blockchain size and the pruning of the blockchain?

Tags: hard-fork, blockchain-size, pruning, protocol, blockchain-data

Will the [upcoming Seraphis upgrade](https://github.com/UkoeHB/Seraphis) change anything with regard to the blockchain size and the pruning of the blockchain?